# How to create a window in c?

Tags: linux, user-interface

I want to create a window, for that I know I have to use gtk+ toolkit,
but how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use an interface designer like [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/).  There is a [Glade tutorial here](http://live.gnome.org/Glade/Tutorials).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the tutorial from: 
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/com_cpp/Cpp/scenarios_quickstarts/gtk_get_started.htm

Or the examples from GTK?